# Too much load time when returning large string from webmethod Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod, load-time

I have a WebMethod in Asp.Net and everything looked to be working fine . Suddenly i had to change some parameters and the queries brought in too much data i check the string `count = 82452`.

The issue is it is taking too much time to show the data . I basically put all the data in a div. And it shows the listing.

Or is it possible the string is broken or something and it is not going to the success function ?But again i think no matter what it should at least go to the success function rite?

Here is the WebMethode:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string getResults(string post)
{
    string newHtml = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
            newHtml += Somefunction();
    }
    return newHtml;
}
```

And here is the JS code:

```
PageMethods.getResults(pageUrl, results_Text);
function results_Text(result, userContext, methodName) {
        alert("adadasD");
        document.getElementById("mainResults").innerHTML += result;
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to show your code that produces the issue

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is related to this question: 
[Return large string from ajax call using Jquery to Web Method of ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915953/return-large-string-from-ajax-call-using-jquery-to-web-method-of-asp-net)

And applying the same answer worked.