# How to return a string, with a long length, in a WebMethod?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, webmethod

I have a `public static` function that returns a string (WebMethod).

I want to put this string in an HTML element.

If the string has a small length, it's ok. However, when the length is too big, I get a 500 error.

My solution is writing the string in a `.txt` file and reading the file in a JavaScript function.

But I don't know if it is the best solution. Is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve/solve?, do you want to render an HTML page on the client-side? please provide the code snippet and update the question for better context.

Comment: See an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915953/return-large-string-from-ajax-call-using-jquery-to-web-method-of-asp-net.